# Change Hyperlink Color in Ionic Toast

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using a service to present toasts to the user, and I am passing through hyperlinks in the toast using innerHTML. The text in the toast is white, and the background is blue. However, the hyperlinks in anchor tags I am passing through are not readable and appear in a slightly lighter blue than the background of the toast. I would just like them to be the same colour as the rest of the text (white).

```
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

async presentToast(message, color, duration, position) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: duration,
      color: color,
      position: position
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```

Then I am using the service like so:

```
 showToast(){
   this.toastService.presentToast('Please <a href = \'https://www.google.co.uk\'  target= \'_blank\'> click me</a>', 'primary', 4000, 'top', );
  }
```

Here are the primary colours that are being passed through:

```
--ion-color-primary: #0000A0;
--ion-color-primary-rgb: 66,140,255;
--ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-primary-shade: #0000A0;
--ion-color-primary-tint: #0000A0;
```

Is there a way to override the hyperlink colour using a css class? Or is there a value in my primary colours I could change to get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both. If you don't want to override the global config then assign a class to your  element and then apply a css styling

```
.toast-link a {
color: ...; // whatever color you'd like
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately this is not working. I have also attempted 

 async presentToast(message, color, duration, position) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: duration,
      color: color,
      position: position,
      cssClass: "toast-link"
    });
    toast.present();
  }


Then in my global scss:

ion-toast.toast-link a {
  color: #fff 
  }

Comment: According to the docs you should be able to use the following if it is set to the base element of the toast:
.toast-link { --color: #fff;}